# Bootstrap glyphicon hover only partially colored

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icon-fonts

I'm utilizing Bootstrap's glyphicon font to render icons within menu links. They have a CSS :hover effect that causes them to change color upon hover. For most of the glyphicons this works perfectly fine, but for some reason, when using the "open folder" icon, the right portion of the icon is *not* properly colored on hover -- it remains the default, unhovered color.

It's only happening on Safari on Mac (seems to work fine on Chrome). I've attached a screenshot. Any thoughts?

[image: Glyphicon hover partially colored issue on Mac Safari]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjusting letter spacing seems to work.

```
.glyphicon{ 
  letter-spacing:3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru8ME/8/

Comment: This is correct: adding `letter-spacing` does fix it. But for the up-to-date working demo, use the fiddle mentioned by Lorenz below: http://jsfiddle.net/Ru8ME/12/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** as suggested by Alex, increase the letter-spacing CSS attribute:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ru8ME/12/

From the fiddle:

```
.glyphicon {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #0C6;
  letter-spacing:6px;
}
.glyphicon:hover {
  color: #F00;
}
```

I can confirm this works on Safari 7.0.2 and Chrome 33 for OS X!

Comment: Both iterations in the fiddle still render improperly in Safari 7.0.2 on Mac.

Comment: add the letter spacing as assisted by Alex above... worked in Chrome on PC... Test in Mac? jsfiddle.net/Ru8ME/8

Answer (score 0):

a quick hack you could do is to add a padding.

```
.glyphicon-folder-open {padding-right: 10px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Mjq7/